# AVAudioPlayer error for Iphone Development

Tags: iphone, avaudioplayer

I am developing an iphone application using "AVAudioPlayer" for playing a ".wav" file . For this i am adding header file "#import " . But while compiling i am getting error like :
          ".objc_class_name_AVAudioPlayer", referenced from:
literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@AVAudioPlayer in WebviewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found collect2: ld returned 1 exit status" .

So can you please tell me the solution for this type of error....

Thanks & Regards,
KamalBhr

"

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the AVFoundation.framework framework to your project.

Comment: hello,

     Thank you for your Quick reply and also thanks for ur suggestion now my application is compiling .

Thnaks ,
KamalBhr

Comment: KamalBhr-- Please select the checkmark beside this answer so that everyone will know the question has been answered and so Nicolas can get credit.